# It is strictly forbidden to play with smartphone?

Tags: grammatical-number

Is it correct to say "It is strictly forbidden to play with smartphone"?
Should I add a the in front even though I am not talking about any definite phone at the moment.
Or should I add s at the end even though it is most likely the person has only one phone.

Context:I am writing a contract and this is one rule that I want to specify in the contract.

Comment: If your only addressing one person, it would be better to say *It is strictly forbidden for you to play with your smartphone.* It wouldn't even matter if they had more than one.

Comment: I don’t know it is permissible to use “you” in a contract. I am no lawyer but it sounds not “legal” enough

Comment: It's perfectly legal if it's a contract with a named individual. (But if there are other people also getting contracts, the person could question if the same clause applies to the others too. Of course, you wouldn't need to tell the person that. Just as you don't need to disclose the salaries of other people. However, I suppose that could then open things up to possible litigation on the basis of discrimination. But, all that aside, the use of *you* itself would not be the problem—especially if you just said that, yes, it did apply to them too.)

Comment: For a contract, you'd better start by carefully defining what it means to "play with" a smart phone.

Comment: I have a suggestion that does not always work but still worth a try. When it doubt, try to put a possessive adjective instead of a,an,the and write it like that. In your sentence for example it would be your smartphones.

Comment: None of it’s correct if you’re spelling it with a ‘k’.

Comment: And as a last comment from me, if you're concerned with legality, don't take any advice from random people on the internet. Always consult a lawyer.

Comment: What if I’m not “playing” with my phone, but using it for a non-play-related purpose?   Are you really looking for “Use of smartphones is prohibited.”

Comment: @jim Yeah I agree your version is better